# AngularJS and BootstrapJS not working together

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've scoured the web to integrate Angular and Bootstrap and have found that I should be using https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/. I have followed a lot of the instructions and this is what I have for my index.html file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.5.3/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/gh-pages/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/gh-pages/ui-bootstrap-1.3.2-csp.css">
    <script src="static/js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="static/js/home.js"></script>
    <script src="static/js/about.js"></script>
    <script src="static/js/bootstraptest.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
         <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

And then, in my app.js file, I have the following:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
 'ngRoute',
 'px_app.home',
 'px_app.about',
 'px_app.bootstraptest',
 'ui.bootstrap'
]);
```

However, when I start up the app, I just get a blank page. Am I missing something here?

Thanks

Comment: Is it all you have in your index.html?

Comment: @Paul Edited with everything.

Comment: where's your content - you haven't included any?

Comment: @DanielA.White Please check my updates. The contents themselves are in the home, about, etc. html and js files.

Comment: a [mcve] would be great.

Comment: @DanielA.White while I agree that "why is my code not working" is not helping here. The reverse question is valid: Give me a simple working example of how to get angular 1.5 and angular-ui-bootstrap working together.

Comment: Cause that's what I think the answer is: take a working simple template and take it from there.

Comment: @flup It's OP's responsibility to provide reproduce-able problem. could be a result of numerous issues not shown or detectable in console even. Certainly nothing shown related to routing to populate `ng-view`

Comment: @intl create a plunker demo that reproduces problem. There isn't enough shown for us to work with

Comment: @intl or start from scratch with a working version and keep it working while adding more and more of your code. That'll help you pinpoint the bit that goes wrong.

Answer (score -1):

It's often hard to get up and running when you need to start from scratch.
Start with a working example instead and take it from there.

Take one of the are plunker links on http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ and work from there. (Note that they don't work in safari! I had to use Chrome to get them to work.) Your page won't be completely empty.

See for example http://plnkr.co/edit/M4r8nohnrmgMOhUfGwm4?p=options which I created by following the "edit in plunker" link for the simple alert case.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="AlertDemoCtrl">
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="alert.html">
    <div class="alert" style="background-color:#fa39c3;color:white" role="alert">
      <div ng-transclude></div>
    </div>
  </script>

  <uib-alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}</uib-alert>
  <uib-alert template-url="alert.html">A happy alert!</uib-alert>
  <button type="button" class='btn btn-default' ng-click="addAlert()">Add Alert</button>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

With example.js

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('AlertDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.alerts = [
    { type: 'danger', msg: 'Oh snap! Change a few things up and try submitting again.' },
    { type: 'success', msg: 'Well done! You successfully read this important alert message.' }
  ];

  $scope.addAlert = function() {
    $scope.alerts.push({msg: 'Another alert!'});
  };

  $scope.closeAlert = function(index) {
    $scope.alerts.splice(index, 1);
  };
});
```

Comment: This doesn't answer anything. It's nothing more than a comment. What exactly is there to *"template"* that can't be created simply from scratch?

Comment: template means a sample project that you can check out right away that works. most projects have one, but the links on the angular bootstrap page are broken.

Comment: Pretty simple to throw it together in plunker. OP hasn't provided enough code though to reproduce problem since no routing templates are defined

Comment: You're using a completely different meaning of the same word template.

Comment: FYI-plunker links on angular-ui site work fine in chrome. I do most of my dev in firefox where they do break for some reason.

Comment: "using different meaning" ... no I'm not... setting this up is fairly trivial

Comment: You're talking about a piece of html with brackets in, I'm talking about a directory filled with files that you can check out to get started. Boilerplate code. The whole point is that you don't want to create it from scratch cause there's nothing specific to your project in there, it's got all the stuff that you need to get started. Links all the proper versions of all the proper libraries and shows a little piece of demo that it works.

Comment: Well that's also fairly trivial using package managers or yeoman

Comment: Apperantly it's not trivial enough cause the OP is looking at a blank page and asking how to get angular and bootstrap to work together. And yes, ideally the template also contains a package.json if the dependencies are nontrivial.

Comment: But @flup how do you know it isn't something simple like incorrect path in routing view template url? Or forgot to create routing to populate `ng-view`? There simply isn't enough known to troubleshoot what OP has shown. Or even something dumb like running this in `file://` protocol. Lots of reasons that it wouldn't work that don't require boilerplate

Comment: True, is hard to tell, but the trick in general is to get things working first. Then add stuff while keeping things working. Then the moment it breaks you know that the last thing you added is the offensive bit. If you start out with a ton of files that have one or more errors in them, it's hard to get to a working situation. And hard to create a simpler example that demonstrates your problem. Exactly cause the problem is in the big pile of all the code together and you don't know which bit is failing.